# redirect www.domain.com to domain.com or other way round?

Tags: redirect, webserver

I'm setting up another website and still run into this issue. Once and for all, I would like to know what are the pros and cons of each method. No external resource seems to provide a decent answer, so I hoped fellow coders can help me. I **don't** want to know HOW to do it, it is fairly easy to find out, I just want to know which one **(wwww. to  null or null to www.)** would be better for my site.

Comment: What webserver are you running? You can do this through htaccess easily if its enabled.

Comment: you are not answering my question. im running apache on linux though.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`.

Advertising the www. part of a domain is now rather antiquated, and besides, without the www., it's shorter. When we post a domain, the general public assumes that we mean the web service unless we specify otherwise.

If there's a question as to whether it's a domain (for less common Top Level Domains like .cc), I'd rather include `http://` than `www.`.

The main reason not to include the www. is because it's shorter (ie. the www. is not necessary).

Put yourself in the reader's shoes, with their short attention spans. Since the www. does not differentiate your website, you want the reader to see and recognize the differentiating part of your domain immediately. The best way to do this is to put the unique part first (without the www.). Plus, social networking and the mobile space like shorter links.

To summarize, the trend is to no longer use www., but to redirect for the people who are in the habit of typing `www.`.

Comment: ok I get that the "www" is somehow implicit today, but the only technical difference will be that one is shorter ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no technical or SEO advantage either way, as long as the redirects work properly.

I prefer no-www, because the 'www.' is simply unnecessary.